# Python: append() weird behavior during recursion

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, recursion, append

I was writing the following program to generate all possible permutations from a given list.

```
def permute(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:

        def __permute(nums, n, chosen, perms):
            if len(perms) == n:
                print(perms)
            else:
                for i in range(n):
                    if chosen[i]:
                        continue
                    else:
                        chosen[i] = True
                        perms.append(nums[i])
                        __permute(nums, n, chosen, perms)
                        perms.pop()
                        chosen[i] = False
            
        n = len(nums)
        __permute(nums, n, [False]*n, [])
```

For example:

```
Input: [1,2,3]
Output:
  [1,2,3]
  [1,3,2]
  [2,1,3]
  [2,3,1]
  [3,1,2]
  [3,2,1]
```

Now this time, I want to add all permutations in a list and return it:

```
Input: [1,2,3]
Output:
[
  [1,2,3],
  [1,3,2],
  [2,1,3],
  [2,3,1],
  [3,1,2],
  [3,2,1]
]
```

Here is my code:

```
def permute(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:

        def __permute(nums, n, chosen, perms,res):
            if len(perms) == n:
                res.append(perms)
            else:
                for i in range(n):
                    if chosen[i]:
                        continue
                    else:
                        chosen[i] = True
                        perms.append(nums[i])
                        __permute(nums, n, chosen, perms, res)
                        perms.pop()
                        chosen[i] = False
            
        n = len(nums)
        res = []
        __permute(nums, n, [False]*n, [], res)
        return res
```

Problem is, the output is full of empty lists.

```
Input: [1,2,3]
Output:
[
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  []
]
```

I fixed the bug by replacing `res.append(perms)` by `res.append(perms[:])` but I don't understand why it works.

I also printed the id() of each `perms` and noticed something weird:

```
>>> print(id(perms))
>>>
140093677843328
140093677843328
140093677843328
140093677843328
140093677843328
140093677843328
>>> print(id(perms[:]))
>>>
140689610181440
140689610145600
140689610145600
140689610145600
140689610145600
140689610145600
```

Does anyone have an explanation to this behavior?

Comment: Because you are *always working with the same `perms` list*. And your algorithm clears that list, `perms.pop()`... so at the end, you end up with a bunch of refernces to the same empty list.

Comment: When `res.append(perms)`, the list `perms` is given as a reference.  This `perms` later becomes empty by `perms.pop()`.  As a result, the returned values are all empty.

Comment: Ah! Got it now, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`perms` is the same object every time, but when you do `perms[:]` you are creating a copy of `perms` (which is a separate object from `perms`).

`res` (list) stores the reference to `perms`, so if change `perms` the same will be reflected on the list `res`.

But doing `res[:]` gives you a copy of `perms` (which is a different object) as mentioned above.